# add different logo for different clients in gsuite

Tags: email, google-workspace

I am having a gsuite account that has approx 9 clients with different email accounts for their firm. I want to change the respective logo of the client for their emails.

For example if a client is of abc company, I want to upload logo of abc for their emails and  if a client is of xyz company, I want to upload logo of xyz for their emails. But if I change the logo of one client, it applies to all the clients in my gsuite account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one logo can be uploaded per GSuite account - see this [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081?hl=en) stating

> You can specify only one logo for your domains. The same logo appears for users in all domains that are part of your account.